# text extraction failing from image pytesser

Tags: python, pytesser

Issue with text extraction. I am new at using image extraction in python.

```
from pytesser import *
import Image 

file = 'C:\\Image1.bmp'
image = Image.open(file)  # Open image object using PIL
print "1",image_to_string(image)     # Run tesseract.exe on image
print "2",image_file_to_string(file)

Text extraction works on Image1.
>> Text

Text extract does NOT work on Image2.
>> C)
```

Suggestions please.
[image: Image1][image: Image2]